# Jquery - Truncate Text by Line (not by character count)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a Jquery script to truncate a text paragraph by line (not by character count).

I would like to achieve an evenly truncated text-block. It should have a "more" and "less" link to expand and shorten the text paragraph. My text paragraph is wrapped in a div with a class, like this:

```
<div class="content">
<h2>Headline</h2>
<p>The paragraph Text here</p>
</div>
```

The closest solution i could find on SOF is the one below (but it`s for textarea element and does not work for me):
[Limiting number of lines in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556767/limiting-number-of-lines-in-textarea)

Many thanks for any tips.
Ben

Answer (score 6):

For a basic approach, you could take a look at the `line-height` CSS property and use that in your calculations.  Bear in mind that this approach will not account for other inline elements  that are larger than that height (e.g. images).

If you want something a bit more advanced, you can get the information about each line using `getClientRects()` function.  This function returns a collection of *TextRectangle* objects with width, height and offset for each one.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456442/how-can-i-highlight-the-line-of-text-that-is-closest-to-the-mouse/2456631#2456631) here for an example (albeit an unrelated goal) of how `getClientRects()` works.

---

Update, had a bit of time to come back and update this answer with an actual example.  It's basic, but you get the idea:

http://jsbin.com/ukaqu3/2

A couple of pointers:

- The collection returned by *getClientRects* is static, it won't update automatically if the containing element's dimensions change.  My example works around this by capturing the window's resize event.
- For some strange standards-compliance reason that I'm not understanding, the element you call *getClientRects* on must be an inline element.  In the example I have, I use a container div with the text in another div inside with `display: inline`.

Comment: that's the way forward, for sure. Didn't know about this, +1

Comment: Looks like something which could be used, thanks. Though, I am unfortunately not smart enough to put the whole script together, including the more/less link. Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: @Bento: the real problem is that javascript requires that the content be rendered first, then modified.  So you have a tradeoff, either render the content in full and shrink it down when it's ready, or render it hidden and then show the amount you need when the document is ready.  It's a very clunky design and you might be better off marking this question as answered and asking another question for some better advice.

Comment: I am not sure how all the Jquery scripts for text truncation dealing with it i.e. before/after. At the moment I am using the following script and the effect is not visible (in case it`s rendering the HTML first and then truncates): http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/

It can`t be too hard of a task, since there are plenty of Jquery plugins out there, but none provides truncation by line (only by character):
http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/truncate+text+type%3Aproject_project

Which questions are you suggesting? Not sure how phrase this in different words.

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

I made this little jQuery code to allow me truncate text blocks by line (via CSS classes), feel free to use and comment it.

**Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samsamX/ps4wZ/3/)**, which also include truncate functions by char count or word count. You can see that currently, resize the window won't refresh the block display, I'm working on it.

```
/*
*   Truncate a text bloc after x lines
*   <p class="t_truncate_l_2">Lorem ipsum magna eiusmod sit labore.</p>
*/  
$("*").filter(function () { 
    return /t_truncate_l_/.test($(this).attr('class')); 
}).each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var content = el.text();
    var classList = el.attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    $.each(classList, function(index, item){
        if(/^t_truncate_l_/.test(item)) {
            var n = item.substr(13);
            var lineHeight = parseInt(el.css('line-height'));
            if(lineHeight == 1 || el.css('line-height') == 'normal')
                lineHeight = parseInt(el.css('font-size')) * 1.3;
            var maxHeight = n * lineHeight;
            var truncated = $.trim(content);
            var old; 
            if(el.height() > maxHeight)
                truncated += '...';
            while(el.height() > maxHeight && old != truncated) {
                old = truncated;
                truncated = truncated.replace(/\s[^\s]*\.\.\.$/, '...'); 
                el.text(truncated);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

why not make the p element with overflow: hidden; give fixed line height, caluclate the height of the div so id contains exactly the number of lines you require and the only change the height of the p from javascript.

```
p{
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height:13px;
    height:26px; /* show only 2 rows */
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    function seeMoreRows(){
        $(p).height("52px");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Though, it seems not flexible enough since all paragraphs on the page have a different length (it`s actually a list of news items). If I expand it to i.e. 52px it might not be enough space for some and too much space for others. It needs to be dynamic somehow.

Comment: it was a example and I think you can calculate the new height dinamycally but Andy's answer looks better than my idea.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small module that works with pure text content, no nested tags and no css-padding on the text-containing element is allowed (but this functionality could easily be added).

The HTML:

```
<p class="ellipsis" data-ellipsis-max-line-count="3">
    Put some multiline text here
</p>
```

The Javascript/Jquery:

```
( function() {

$(document).ready(function(){
    store_contents();
    lazy_update(1000);
});

// Lazy update saves performance for other tasks...
var lazy_update = function(delay) {

    window.lazy_update_timeout = setTimeout(function(){

        update_ellipsis();

        $(window).one('resize', function() {
            lazy_update(delay);
        });

    }, delay);
}

var store_contents = function(){

    $('.ellipsis').each(function(){
        var p = $(this);
        p.data('ellipsis-storage', p.html());
    });
}

var update_ellipsis = function(){

    $('.ellipsis').each(function(){

        var p = $(this);
        var max_line_count = p.data('ellipsis-max-line-count');
        var line_height = p.html('&nbsp').outerHeight();
        var max_height = max_line_count*line_height;
        p.html(p.data('ellipsis-storage'));
        var p_height = p.outerHeight();

        while(p_height > max_height){

            var content_arr = p.html().split(' ');
            content_arr.pop();
            content_arr.pop();
            content_arr.push('...');
            p.html(content_arr.join(' '));
            p_height = p.outerHeight();
        }
    });
}

} )();
```

I hope you like it!

Answer (score 0):

If you used a monospaced font, you'd have a shot at this working, as you'd have a good idea how many letters fit onto each line, for an element of a defined width. However, if a word breaks across lines, then this might get tricky..

e: found another question which is basically what you're after - they didn't really have a resolution either, but to my mind, the line-height and element height seems closest.

["How can I count text lines inside a dom element"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783899/how-can-i-count-text-lines-inside-an-dom-element-can-i)

Answer (score -1):

**tl;dr -** set a height on your container div and then use the [jQuery dotdotdot plugin](https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.dotdotdot)

Was about to make @Andy E's awesome example into a plugin, but then realized https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.dotdotdot could pull this off.  Our use case is we want to show one line on desktop widths and two lines on mobile/tablet.

Our CSS will just set the container div to the equivalent of one or two line-height's accordingly and then the dotdotdot plugin appears to handle the rest.