# Access HTML text layout information from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way in JavaScript to get information about how the browser has placed the line change(Newline) for text in a `p` tag?

What I need is the ability to move and draw something similar to a "cursor" within a `p` tag.

Left and right are easy enough to handle, but in order to move the cursor up/down I need to know where the browser has placed the line change, and I can't seem to find that. Is it possible?

What I am trying to do is a bit more complicated then then description above. This description is just the core of my problem.

I can't use a rich text area, and the real keyboard cursor to handle my use case.

Comment: `[contenteditable]` and a *lot* of `<span>`s.

Comment: the "core" of your problem was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7431801/982924

Comment: How would that work? <span> tag's don't contain any line information

Comment: RAGS: That would work, but it seems like an ugly hacked way to do it . But I guess that mean that there is no direct javascript supported to do it -(