# wrap lines in span respecting tags

Tags: jquery, string, split

**I need to wrap lines in a text in separate spans.**
I found an answer which does (almost) exactly what I need...

> [plugin to wrap text example](http://pmbennett.net/demos/jquery-finding-lines-of-text.html)

```js
$.fn.wrapLines = function (options) {
    var options = $.extend({
        lineWrap: 'span',
        lineClassPrefix: 'wrapliner wrap_line_',
        wordClassPrefix: 'w_line_',
        index: 0,
        offsetTop: 0,
        offsetLeft: 0
    }, options);
    return this.each(function () {
        options.index = 0;
        options.offset = 0;
        var parentElm = $(this);
        var elmText = $(parentElm).text();
        $(parentElm).html(function (ind, htm) {
            var $repText = '<' + options.lineWrap + '>' + elmText.replace(/\s+/g, ' </' + options.lineWrap + '> <' + options.lineWrap + '>');
            $repText = $repText + '</' + options.lineWrap + '>';
            return $repText;
        });
        $(options.lineWrap, parentElm).each(function () {
            var spanOffset = $(this).offset();
            if (spanOffset.top > options.offsetTop) {
                options.offsetTop = spanOffset.top;
                options.index++;
            }
            $(this).addClass(options.wordClassPrefix + options.index);
        });

        if ($.browser.msie && ($.browser.version == 7 || $.browser.version == 8)) {
            for (var x = 1; x <= options.index; x++) {
                var $spans = $('.' + options.wordClassPrefix + x);
                $spans
                .eq($spans.length - 1)
                .removeClass(options.wordClassPrefix + x)
                .addClass(options.wordClassPrefix + (x + 1))
            }
        }
        for (var x = 1; x <= options.index; x++) {
            $('.' + options.wordClassPrefix + x, parentElm)
            .wrapAll('<' + options.lineWrap + ' class="' + options.lineClassPrefix + x + '" />')
            .append("");
            var innerText = $('.' + options.lineClassPrefix + x, parentElm).text();
            $('.' + options.lineClassPrefix + x, parentElm).html(function () {
                return innerText;
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Yet, I want to preserve tags.

I tried around changing the `.text` to `.html` and adjusting the regular expression, but I can't seem to find the answer. ...I'm no expert with regex

#### Maybe someone can help me with this.

here's a fiddle of my current implementation that only gets the text.

> [only use Text jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/jpvKQ/1/)

here's a fiddle that preserves tags, but does not wrap the text before tags correctly

> [does not wrap before tags jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/jpvKQ/2/)

Here's another example which I found. It wraps the words perfectly, but does not wrap the lines

> [wrap Words preserving tags jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wabK/)

Comment: Looking at the code/markup your solution wraps each word in a span not line. Is that your intent?

Comment: @JamesSouth it wraps the words AND the lines. which is actually fine. I really only need to wrap the lines. I found quite a few examples on StackOverflow but none seemed to respect tags and split into lines.

Comment: I take it you want soft line breaks then (wrapping text). Hard line breaks is dead easy but you'll need to do some calculations to do soft. This question might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671713/detecting-line-breaks-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the correct pattern.

> > [workin jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/jpvKQ/4/)

this is the pattern I used `/(<\s*.*?[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\s*.*?>)|(\s+)/ig`

```
// returns all spaces or tags with their content
.replace(/(<\s*.*?[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\s*.*?>)|(\s+)/ig, '$1')
```

This is still not perfect, since it will not allow breaking lines inside child-tags, but it does what I want for my specific reason.

Maybe someone can use it.

Still looking forward to other implementations.