# Removing the last line of a paragraph

Tags: jquery

```
<span class="locationtitle">
    <a href="#">Test Text</a><br>
    6:00 p.m. - 12:00 a.m.<br>
    Repeat on the first Thursday
</span>
```

I am trying to come up with a way with jQuery to remove the last sentence.  So everything after the 2nd `<br>`. The text in that sentence potentially could be anything so doing a `find()` won't work.

Comment: You mean after `<br>` ?

Comment: Duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671713/detecting-line-breaks-with-jquery

Comment: sorry yes after the second <br>

Comment: @Lior As OP wants to use `<br>` I don't think the question you link too is related.

Comment: The *best* solution would be for you to wrap that last sentence in a new `<span class="something-unique">` and hide that in the usual manner.

Comment: I'm not generating the orginal source and have no control over how it comes out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this :

```
$('.locationtitle').html(function(_,html) { 
    return html.split(/<br\s*\/?>/i).slice(0,-1).join('<br>')
});
```

This supports other ways to write the `<br>`, for example `<BR/>`, you could use

Some explanation :

- jQuery's [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) callback takes two arguments, I don't need the first one (the index)
- [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) makes an array from a string, using the `<br>` (or its variants) as separator
- [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) returns a copy of the array without the last element
- [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) makes a string back from the array, inserting the needed `<br>`

Comment: That's a nice one except the string could be _split_ at `/<br\s*\/?>/`

Comment: @Ejay If OP uses other kind of `<br>`, yes.

Comment: A little explanation would be appreciated here. What are the arguments in html(), for example? What is join() doing?

Comment: Nice. Thanks. I'm assuming that you have to join the BR because it's technically part of the array element that gets cut?

Comment: `['aa','bb','cc'].join('<br>')` ===> `'aa<br>bb<br>cc'`

Comment: ok so a new wrinkle to this is the third line is not always there. So rather than deleting the last line I would need to delete whatever is after the 2nd <br>

Comment: @MarkK If you want to keep only the first two lines replace `slice(0,-1)` with `slice(0,2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that last sentence doesn't contain any HTML, a mixture of vanilla JS and jQuery may work best here:

```
var s = $('.locationtitle')[0].childNodes; // HTML and text nodes
var last = s[s.length-1];                  // selects the last node
$(last).wrap('<span>').parent().hide();    // can only hide HTML elements
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/NXZpL/

Comment: Doesn't work if you add other elements. See the example I gave to the other wrong answer.

Comment: Much like Mohammad Adil's answer, this only removes the last node, rather than everything after the last <br> tag as the OP requested.