# jquery get span content with carriage return on key up event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get span content with carriage return on key up event but i could not able to achieve it.

I've one `text field` and `div` to display what I've typed in text field and I've to save div content with carriage return value.

I've tried an example updating div on text filed key up event when i am typing div content is getting auto wrap but I've no idea who to get div content with carriage return value.

Here is my example http://jsbin.com/UtodICI/1/edit

Comment: I found solution in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671713/detecting-line-breaks-with-jquery?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Span requires `display:block` css

Adding CSS

```
.txt { display:block; border:1px solid red }
```

will show that your code works and sets the height based on the input ( if the input is a number )

`display:block` is what is required to change the span to a block element and able to respond to height values.

( if I am correct, this is what you are asking )

Comment: @Rod i am asking how to get div content with carriage return value?.