# How to highlight lines with background colour and have padding on each line?

Tags: php, javascript, css

I am using php to output and exerpt inside a p tag.

I am then wrapping the inside string of the p tag with a span.

```
<p class="lead"><span><?php the_advanced_excerpt(); ?></span></p>
```

The outputted html...

```
<p class="lead"><span>Motorcycle helmet Full face or open face. A motocross or enduro style helmet is a better choice. These are specifically designed for off-road use and have particular…</span></p>
```

The span then has this css on it...

```
.carousel-caption .lead span {
    background: #F60;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Please see the out come here...

[image]

**See the green arrows - where it looks as desired.

See the red arrows - where padding is missing.**

As you can see the orange high lighted lines are flush at the end of each line. Apart from the beginning and the end of the string.

So my question is how can I add left/right padding to each of the lines?

So it appears that each line has been highlighted with a background colour. Like plastic tape that you get embossed letters on.

Is this posible somehow?

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP source.

Comment: The padding shows up on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DnFJP/

Comment: Why not have the background color on your .carousel-caption, that way the background is always orange? unless I am missing something.

Comment: @RyanSaxe on single lines it works fine, on multiple lines, the edges are flush, apart from the first and last words on the paragraph. See here http://jsfiddle.net/DnFJP/1/

Comment: @Cam please see my images above - have highlight the problems

Comment: unfortunately since it really all is one line and just breaking lines because of space, I don't think you can do what you want. See my answer for more detail on why

Comment: you can add padding to the paragraph and make the text left aligned? should have the same effect

Comment: @Amitd tried that - does not work http://jsfiddle.net/DnFJP/2/

Comment: This may help a little http://stackoverflow.com/a/4148445/258674

Comment: @dev-null-dweller thanks I found this - but perhaps maybe is seems for trouble that it's work - I will see if I can figure it out, but looks difficult.

Comment: Only way I was able to do this is by explicitly defining each line break and each line as its own <div> with padding and line-height.  Perhaps you could use PHP to set a word limit per line and generate a new <div> once that limit has been reached?  Here's an example: www.laudeomedia.com - you have to add a display:inline style to each  div.  Otherwise the red background color will exceed the width of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Add "display: block" or "display:inline-block" to span's class

Comment: I don't think that will do what I desire. Please see updated question above.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not think it is possible, and this is why:

`span` is always inline like this, so padding adds an extra 5px on the top, bottom, left, and right. Now your middle lines are not the beginning or the end because they are one line, so padding does not read for them.

You can set a background with `display:block` but you want a "highlighted" effect, which is not what `display:block` will give

Comment: Hmmmm is there not any sneaky of adding spans to each line using jquery or something?

Comment: unfortunately I do not believe so. I considered it, but the line-break points are subjective to the size and such and it is only for styling so I am pretty sure you cannot determine it. There is one thing, but it's not a good idea...use jquery or php to calculate about how many characters before a theoretical line-break and add a space, but that has potential to go wrong

Comment: Thanks for your help ryan - seems for trouble than its worth :(