# CSS format second line differently from first line

Tags: html, css

Is there any way purely with CSS (or 'proper' markup) to style the 2nd line of a paragraph when the text wraps to a second line? A well placed `<br />` would do it, but I don't believe that's good markup or SEO.

Specifically, say I have a paragraph that is 2 lines long. I would like the 2nd line to have a wider width than the first line. So the paragraph is a little "pyramid-like". But I don't want to use anything that's not a proper way to do this just for beauty's sake.

Example:

```
<p>I am a very long 
sentence where my second line is longer.</p>
```

Comment: Did you add that second paragraph to your question after I wrote my answer, or did I just not notice it? My current answer does not help you once you consider that second paragraph.

Comment: That was in the original question, but I think I need to clarify. I want the paragraph to be normal, i.e., no line breaks. so `<p>I am a very long sentences....</p>`. With the styling provided below, I can target first line with coloring successfully, but not width. I tried `width: 50%`, `width: 50px`, `margin-right:50px`, `padding: 30px` but it doesn't have an effect on the width.

Comment: I understand what you're after now (though it's still confusing :p), and I'm 99% sure that CSS can't do it alone. You'd have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, you confirmed my theory then! ;) Can't be done. Will give up on this styling attempt.

Comment: Yup, it makes sense to stick to CSS for things like this. If you're curious, the JavaScript would have been a *very* cut down version of this: http://jsfiddle.net/UGBXD/11/ / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529936/moz-background-inline-policy-on-webkit/5564206#5564206

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the [`:first-line` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/X33pY/ - resize the window to make a second line in the first paragraph.

```css
p:first-line {
    color: red
}
p {
    color: blue
}
```

---

Just in case, this might be what you're after:

http://jsfiddle.net/qKRh8/

```css
p {
    white-space: pre
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that, as shown in the fiddle, "second line" does not refer to second line in HTML, as in HTML a newline is the same as a normal space character. "second line" refers to the second line as displayed on the browser.

Comment: @Bolt: Thanks. I cottoned on to that, and added an explanation sentence in my answer.

Comment: Note that you can't do box formatting with [`:first-line`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#first-line-pseudo): "The :first-line pseudo-element is similar to an inline-level element, but with certain restrictions. The following properties apply to a :first-line pseudo-element: font properties, color property, background properties, 'word-spacing', 'letter-spacing', 'text-decoration', 'text-transform', and 'line-height'. UAs may apply other properties as well."

Comment: Ah, that's what I was just realizing! I don't think any of those will help me shrink the first line width.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :first-line pseudo-class to style the first line and, by implication, the second line will fall back to the default styling.

See:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-elements