# CSS - apply padding to inline element across two lines

Tags: html, css

I have to create a style to apply a background color and padding to a header element, resulting the following intended appearance (Photoshop mock-up):

[image]

My CSS is as follows (edited to show relevant rules)

```
h1 {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.4;
    background: #41a293;
    padding: 2px 4px; 
    display:inline;
}
```

This produces the following result:

[image]

I get padding at the start of the element ('S'), and at the very end ('e'), but not where the text breaks. The break happens due to the width of it's parent DIV. This will happen often and is necessary.

Is there any way to ensure the element gets even padding at the points where the text breaks?

Many thanks
Dave

EDIT - I should have also said that the text content will display via a CMS (Wordpress).

Comment: **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6qVVD/

Comment: @thirtydot - yep 80% of users for this site IE :)

Comment: Have a look at my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529936/moz-background-inline-policy-on-webkit). It took me several time and a bounty to get this work, but in the end I got it!

Comment: What kind of solution do you want?  CCS, JS, either or both?

Comment: display: block; seems to have worked for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using jQuery to wrap every word inside your h1 into a span will pretty much do the trick. I have no clue how it affects SEO though to be honest.

This is what i'm using when i need to achieve this.

```
$("h1").each(function() 
    {
        var headerContent = $(this).text().split(' ');

        for (var i = 1; i < headerContent.length; i++) 
        {
            headerContent[i] = '<span class="subhead">' + headerContent[i] + '</span>';
        }

        $(this).html(headerContent.join(' '));
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cnuzh/

I think i actually got this from an answer from a similar question here on stackoverflow a while back. I'll post the link to the original author if this is the case. I shall look into it tomorrow, but first i need my nice warm bed ^^

Hope it helped,

WJ

Comment: Well, thanks, this is the solution that works, but at a high cost I'd say, as this is the resulting markup: http://cl.ly/1s0K112z1S2D283k1f27. This is a serious negative for SEO for an H1. But jeez, this seems to be the only way it will realistically work for authors maintaining the site.

Comment: This can cause an HTML injection attack if you run this with a user-controlled `<h1>` on your site.

Answer (score 19):

If you're okay with the effect only being visible in WebKit/Blink browsers, you should use

```
-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
box-decoration-break: clone;
```

Which does exactly what you want, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cnuzh/13/

Comment: Dunno if it's the best solution for the ts, but it really helped me! Tnx

Comment: for IE you can use 'white-space: pre-wrap' instead

Answer (score 2):

if you add

```
white-space:pre-wrap;
```

to your h1 it will look like this :

[image]

Still trying to figure a way to add the space before the (i) !

EDIT : Check this out :
http://jsfiddle.net/ahmad/6qVVD/10/

--Still need a way to wrap the last word with jQuery--

Wrapping the last word with a span using jQuery

```
$('h1').each(function(index, element) {
    var heading = $(element), word_array, last_word, first_part;

    word_array = heading.html().split(/\s+/); // split on spaces
    last_word = word_array.pop();             // pop the last word
    first_part = word_array.join(' ');        // rejoin the first words together

    heading.html([first_part, ' <span>', last_word, '</span>'].join(''));
});
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/6qVVD/12/

As you see it's working perfectly

Comment: Do you know a way to wrap the last word using jQuery? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Updated the answer and added a way to wrap the last word with span

Comment: This only works with that exact phrase. if you increase the length of text you still have issues: http://jsfiddle.net/6qVVD/48/

Answer (score 2):

Inline elements do not support padding and margin well, so make it block or inline-block (which is not cross browser)
Why are you making it inline btw?

Comment: Because if if is not inline, the result looks like this: http://cl.ly/1d2c261m0N1P1Z2C113Y

Answer (score 2):

My boss loves using this feature in his designs recently, so I've had to come up with some solutions. Luckily for most of the ones we're doing, they are for titles on Sliders which will always be on two lines, so I took to using before and afters to insert a 10px line before each line of text. Not great cross browser compatibility I know, but works okay and doesn't look appalling in IE.

Here's a little jsFiddle to explain it:

http://jsfiddle.net/mP5vg/

This is the only pure CSS solution I could find.

P.S. Sorry for my messy code.

Comment: Nice solution if you dont need to support IE7

Answer (score 1):

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/korigan/jzm3qu1q/1/

HTML

```
 <div class="wrap">
     <p class="highlight">
        <span class="text">Amet assumenda atque eos excepturi harum ipsa</span>
     </p>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    width: 150px;
}
.highlight {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline;
    background: blue;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.highlight .text {
        padding: 4px;
        box-shadow: 4px 0 0 blue, -4px 0 0 blue;
        background-color: blue;
        box-decoration-break: clone; /* For Firefox */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: nvm, didn't notice the white line; wouldn't giving & nbsp ; instead of regular spaces help?

<strike>give it an inline-block display, be sure to make it display:inline for ie7</strike>

<strike>regular</strike>

```
h1 { display:inline-block }
```

<strike>ie7 only</strike>

```
h1 { display:inline}
```

Comment: Adding non-breaking space(`&nbsp`) will just disable word wrapping.

Comment: Again, if the content comes from a CMS, users cannot add &nbsp to the text

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more trick for that:

Put `<H1>` in another div and give it border-left, but before it delete padding from `<H1>` css

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="fix">
       <h1>Specialists in retirement income</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { background:#ddd; }
#wrap { width:400px; background:white; }

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    background: #41a293;
    display: inline;
    word-spacing:10px;
    font: 30px/1.4 Arial, sans-serif;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}

.fix {
    border-left:20px solid #41a293;
    }
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qVVD/43/)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe `white-space:nowrap;` is some solution.

Comment: Yes, this maintains padding at each end, but the breaks are necessary, as this approach means the <h1> spills outside it's parent DIV: http://cl.ly/2F2P2Q3I1M0h2V1V2i0T

Answer (score -1):

According to this [thread on WebmasterWorld](http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3943881.htm), which is 2 year-old BTW, this should happen according to the [W3 recommendations](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting).

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/laheab/6MhDU/

Just give each word its own `<p>` element and you should still get the desired effect.

Comment: Problem with that approach is that the content comes from a Wordpress backend, thanks though

Comment: Ah, right. Even so, I'd like the title to be an <h1>. Not too keen on having each letter of a header wrapped in a <p>.

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in an `<h1>`? Not sure if that does the SEO effect though.