# CSS: inline paragraph clear / margin-bottom

Tags: html, css

Following HTML is rendered by the CMS (I can't modify the HTML, but I can change the CSS).

```css
.teaser p {
  display: inline;
  clear: both;
  background-color: red; 
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="teaser">
<p>This is paragraph one</p>
<p>This is paragraph two...</p>
</div>
```

I want to achieve that every line of the paragraph has the background color - not the whole paragraph as a box. Something like this:

[image]

The image above was used in the following post - they added SPANs in the P-tag which I can't do:
[CSS : Background-color on multi-line text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709313/css-background-color-on-multi-line-text)

Is there any posibility to add a break after each paragraph and add the margin-bottom by using pure CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use newlines as content of :after?

```css
.teaser {
  display: block;
  width: 4em;
}
.teaser p {
  display: inline;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.teaser p:after {
  content: "\A\A";
  white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="teaser">
  <p>This is paragraph one</p>
  <p>This is paragraph two...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Background should take as much space as needed by text width and not 100%. Check the image in the question.

Comment: The "display: inline-block;" shows the background-color for the whole block and not line wise, like the screenshot shows.

Comment: Edited again. No margin-bottom, but you can hack with newlines count and font-size.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by setting `display` property to `table` value:

```css
.teaser p {
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="teaser">
    <p>This is paragraph one</p>
    <p>This is paragraph two...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: "display: table" shows the background color of the paragraph as block and not line wise.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your question, but this should do the trick:

```
.teaser p {
display: block;
clear: both;
background-color: red; 
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Of course if you want to remove the margin just add  margin:0

Comment: I need "display: inline;" because I don't want to have the background-color behind the whole paragraph but behind each line. See screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer: This is a modified version of the code used on
>   [www.webdesignerdepot.com/](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/) (hover a blog post title)

You can achieve something similar with a background gradient but adjusting the `line-height` will cause gaps between the rows. It also relies on the element being `inline` meaning that vertical margins won't work. Hence the `<br>`'s to separate the `p`'s:

Edit: you can get around the line height issue by adding some padding to the `p`'s

```css
.teaser {
    width: 60%;
}

.teaser p {
  display: inline;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 130%;
  padding: 3px;

  background-size: 202.22% auto;
  -webkit-background-size: 202.22% auto;
  -moz-background-size: 202.22% auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #000 50%);
  transition: background-position 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.5s ease-out;
  background-position: -98.99% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="teaser">
    <p>This is paragraph one This is paragraph one This is paragraph one This is paragraph one</p>
    <br><br>
    <p>This is paragraph one This is paragraph one This is paragraph one This is paragraph one</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example the "<br><br>" does the margin-bottom, but I can't add additional html :-(

Comment: Yeah sorry. I realised afterwards. I've been trying to find a way to make this work without the br's but I'm struggling