# How to get rid of space between lines of multiline span?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qmn8q2ck/

```
<p>
    <span> This is some multiline text. This is some multiline text. </span><span>This is some multiline text. This is some multiline text. This is some multiline text. This is some multiline text. This is some multiline text. This is some multiline text. This is some multiline text. </span>
</p>

span {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline;
}
```

[image]

However, I noticed that browser highlighting doesn't have spaces between lines, and has the effect that I would like.

[image]

How do I get this effect?

**Edited** to show need for display:inline and effecting the span elements as opposed to the whole paragraph.

Comment: You want that the text will be displayed as 1 line and won't 'break'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709313/css-background-color-on-multi-line-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With css line-height property

```
p { /* or span as you like */
   line-height: 90%; /* Try some values here */
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without changing the line height? I would effectively like to increase the "content" area without changing the actual appearance.

Comment: I did this, and for larger line-heights, I added padding.

Comment: Thanks @knightian! I was nearly going mad as everywhere the advice is to adjust line-height and that might not be an option. Setting a small padding of 1px at the bottom did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can add to your span css display:inline-block

```
span {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/qmn8q2ck/

OR add padding

**DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/ckhfa8hc/

```
span {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

could you please explain your problem in detail? .. from what i understood..

you should probably apply background-color property to the paragraph instead of the span

`p {
    background-color: red;
}`

try this