# Multiline text highlight css in email design

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm trying to create a highlight effect for a headline using css, see [css-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/) for background.

[Here's a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709313/css-background-color-on-multi-line-text) that has solutions that work in the browser using `box-shadow` declaration, but email clients like Gmail [don't support a lot of the newer CSS3 features](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Is there a workaround for doing CSS-based text highlighting that works and can be used in email templates?

Answer (score 2):

When working with HTML email, you have to go really old-fashioned with your code.  I don't think you can give a block of inline text a background color, but you can give a box like a table cell a background color fairly reliably.

```html
The following text is highlighted: <table><tr><td bgcolor="eeff00">Highlighted Text</td></tr></table>

This probably won't even be highlighted in email clients: <span style="background-color: #eeff00">Highlighted Text</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

An old trick could be using double texts (adjust the shadow color to fit your requirements).

*Updated, with `opacity`, which might work and will give it even more "shadow-ish" look*

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center">
  <span style="font-family: Verdana; position: relative">
    <span style="position: absolute; left: 2px; top: 2px; width: 100%; color: #f00; opacity: 0.5; ">
      Service Request Created
    </span>
    <span style="position: relative">
      Service Request Created
    </span>
  </span>
</h1>
```