# text background new line padding issue

Tags: css

I am dealing with text blocks (background blocks over text) and face some issues with paddings on new line. The problem occurs when the browser(e.g. mobile) cuts the text into to two lines due to lack of width. text then looks like this:
[image: padding]

I don't really know how to set a padding css on the end of the new lines, since it could break up anywhere of the sentence. You could say put a span on it with padding, but it is not fixed where the line will break down. It depends on the width. Any recommendations?

Comment: how about trying margin?

Comment: how about wraping text in <p> and style that <p>

Comment: plz tell me how to add margin to breakpoints then. There is no fixed breakpoint, it differs depending on the width

Comment: I already tried p tag but then the entire block get one background as a square

Comment: Will it be possible to share the code?

Comment: Please make a fiddle for this issue

Comment: This could be a tricky one to solve without JavaScript. Here's a fiddle for experimentation: https://codepen.io/Kaivosukeltaja/pen/ybbJGE

Comment: apparently this could work, as seen in another post https://stackoverflow.com/a/19377279/18166526

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply `display: inline-block` but that will turn the background color into an ugly box which doesn't look as nice as having an exact width background for each line. Unfortunately CSS doesn't let us target individual lines except for the first one.

If you don't mind getting a little "creative" (or hacky) you could wrap each word in its own element in the backend or using JavaScript and apply the background color to those elements. Adjust the parent's `word-spacing` accordingly to eliminate gaps.

```css
.main {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #99c;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.text-container {
  max-width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  word-spacing: -15px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-container::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

span {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em 0.25em 0;
  max-width: 360px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="text-container">
    <span>A</span> <span>Movie</span> <span>in</span> <span>the</span> <span>park:</span> <span>Kung</span> <span>Fu</span> <span>Panda</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works great for solid colors! but when I try to replace the background color with some transaparant rgba it overlaps the color and becomes black at crosspoints. Any fix for this? https://jsfiddle.net/djh4mLbu/

Comment: @TinaFlorijn: sure there is a fix, but not a pretty one. Let's render the text twice - first with a solid black background and give its container a lower opacity. Then a second time with just the text at full opacity. https://jsfiddle.net/djh4mLbu/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use box-shadow for this issue and display inline:

```
<div class="text">
    <span class="text-container">A Movie in the park: Kung Fu Panda</span>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.text > span {
    display: inline;
    box-shadow: 25px 0 0 black, -10px 0 0 black;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;            
}
```

Comment: This one actually works. Don't add any left/right padding or you will again have multi-line issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `&nbsp;` after "Park:" and before "Kung"

Answer (score 0):

padding workded!!!
change width by console browser and see result:

```css
h1{
    background-color: #ff6a6a;
    padding: 33px;
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width:300px
}
```

```html
<h1>rert ert erttttttttttttttt 00000000000000000000 dfgdfgd dfgdfgdft ertert  </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question, but still useful to know that CSS property:

```
box-decoration-break: clone;
```

does the job.

> Controls whether the box's margins, borders, padding, and other decorations wrap the broken edges of the box fragments, when the box is split by a break

Browser support is pretty good nowadays: https://caniuse.com/css-boxdecorationbreak

Answer (score -1):

Use `<p>` tag to wrap up the text and it apparently works [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmmmPj)

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="text-container">
    <p id="test">A Movie in the park: Kung Fu Panda</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.main {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #99c;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.text-container {
  max-width: 400px;
}

p {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0.5em;
  max-width: 360px;
}
```